# 2D array increase row and column number with realloc() in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm still learning about array pointers in C and dynamic memory allocation. I'm having some trouble with using the realloc() method for increasing the number of columns and then rows of a 2D array. In this method, I want to adjust the array size according to user input.

```
char **read(int *rows, int *columns){
        char **array = NULL;
        char input;
        int sizeRow = 0;
        int sizeCol = 0;
        int r = 0;
        int c;
        do{
            for(c = 0; ((input = getchar()) != '\n'); ++c){
                if (c == sizeCol) {
                    sizeCol = 1 + sizeCol * 3/2;
                    *(array) = (char *)realloc(array, sizeCol * sizeof *(array)[r]);
                }
                array[r][c] = input;
            }
            if (r == sizeRow) {
                    sizeRow = 1 + sizeRow * 3/2;
                    array = (char **)realloc(array, sizeRow * sizeof **array);
                }
            r++;
        }while (input != EOF);
        return array;
    }
```

The error I'm getting is: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: what is `w`, did you mean `r`?

Comment: You need to rethink your logic flow.  If `array` is NULL, what happens when you do `*(array)`?

Comment: Detail `char **Array` is not a 2D array.  That is a [pointer to pointer to char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+**p).  [`char TwoD[3][4];`](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+TwoD%5B3%5D%5B4%5D) is an 2D array.

Comment: Note `for(c = 0; ((input = getchar()) != '\n'); ++c){...}` is an infinite loop when end-of-file encountered.

Comment: Do you want an array of _string_ pointers?  How should the calling code determine the number of lines read?  Maybe append a final `NULL` pointer as the last string pointer.

Comment: I wanted to get a 2D array of char type elements, so an array of strings, because then I need to use the array in a different function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer in the line `*(array) = (char *)realloc(array, sizeCol * sizeof *(array)[r]);` . On the first iteration of the `do-while` loop, `array` is still `NULL` at that point, so `*(array)` causes a segfault. Simply swap the order of the `if (r == sizeRow) { ... }` and `for(c = 0; ((input = getchar()) != '\n'); ++c) { ... }` blocks.

There are three other issues that I spot as well:

- `*(array) = (char *)realloc(array, sizeCol * sizeof *(array)[r]);` should be `*(array) = (char *)realloc(*array, sizeCol * sizeof *(array)[r]);`
- `array = (char **)realloc(array, sizeRow * sizeof **array);` should be `array = (char **)realloc(array, sizeRow * sizeof *array);`
- The `do-while` loop will never terminate. For the `for` loop to terminate, `input` MUST equal `'\n'` . Since input is not assigned again in the `do-while` loop, when it gets to the end it will NEVER equal `EOF` and thus will ALWAYS continue.

EDIT: one more issue: swap your row-reallocation code for this, in order to zero out the newly allocated part of the array:

```
if (r == sizeRow) {
    int newSizeRow = 1 + sizeRow * 3/2;
    array = (char **)realloc(array, newSizeRow * sizeof *array);
    memset(&array[sizeRow], 0, newSizeRow - sizeRow);
    sizeRow = newSizeRow;
}
```

Comment: I get this error now: malloc: *** error for object 0x8000000000000000: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

Comment: Oh yeah, there's one more little issue. `realloc()` doesn't zero the 'new' memory, so the nested reallocation breaks when you try to reallocate garbage. I'll add to the answer since code blocks don't work in comments